# Problem in formatting binary trees

Tags: formatting, tikz-trees

I am trying to create a binary search tree in LaTeX.

There are two nodes that overlap "blocking" each other.

Does anyone have any experience with this and know how to fix it? I will show my code here as well as a picture of the problem.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[circle,draw](z){$4$}
    child{
        node[circle,draw]{1} 
        child[missing] 
        child{node[circle,draw]{2}}
    }    
    child{
        node[circle,draw]{6} 
        child{node[circle, draw]{5}} 
        child{node[circle,draw]{9}  
        child{node[circle, draw]{7}} child[missing]}};
\end{tikzpicture} \\
```

Here is a picture of the issue:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `level distance` and `sibling distance` for example, using the option

`\begin{tikzpicture}[level distance=15mm,level/.style={sibling distance=40mm/#1}]`

or more elaborately:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[level distance=10mm,
level 1/.style={sibling distance=32mm},
level 2/.style={sibling distance=16mm},
level 3/.style={sibling distance=8mm}]
\node[circle,draw](z){$4$}
child{
    node[circle,draw]{1} child[missing] child{node[circle,draw]{2}}
}
child{
    node[circle,draw]{6} child{node[circle, draw]{5}} child{node[circle,draw]{9}  
child{node[circle, draw]{7}} child[missing]}};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Both methods work.

Answer (score 1):

The TikZ manual is very well written and has several examples to help us understand how it works and how to use it. One of its tutorials addresses this problem "A Lecture Map for Johannes". The first example Till uses shows the issue, quoting him

> The overlap of the nodes is due to the fact that TikZ is not particularly smart when it comes to placing child nodes. Even though it is possible to configure TikZ to use rather clever placement methods, TikZ has no way of taking the actual size of the child nodes into account. This may seem strange but the reason is that the child nodes are rendered and placed one at a time, so the size of the last node is not known when the first node is being processed. In essence, you have to specify appropriate level and sibling node spacings “by hand.”

As @corporal shows in his/hers answer, which is the manual solution.

Further in TikZ manual is the `graphdrawing` library. It's built to help us draw figures like flowcharts and trees that follow a logic to their structure. With it, we inform TikZ the "logic" of our figure and it uses algorithms to lay out the drawing. It's usage is rather advanced but can be extremely useful depending on the size/logic of the respective figure. It's huge advantage is that there's no need to specify any node position, only the relationship between each other. A drawback to the `graphdrawing` library is that it needs to be compiled with `luatex`.

Here's a MWE that uses `graphdrawing` and therefore `lua` to build the OP graph. Note that there's no specification of position nor node spacing.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs,graphdrawing}
\usegdlibrary{trees}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
     \graph [binary tree layout, nodes={draw,circle}] { 4 -- {
            1 -- 2,
            6 -- {
                5,
                9 -- 7}}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]